# "work your way up to becoming a director" — "becoming" but not "to become"?

Tags: infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

> work your way up to becoming a director

Why we use becoming but not to become ?

Comment: What support do you have that the first sentence is correct and the latter is not? Did you see this posted somewhere? Can you explain the context in which it was found?

Answer (score 3):

***[Work your way up](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/work-your-way-up)*** in an idiomatic expression: 
​

> - to achieve a better position within the organization you work for:
>     *She quickly worked her way up to vice president.*

<sup>(Cambridge Dictionary)</sup>

Actually "way up to" is more commonly followed by the bare infinitive, but also the gerund is used as shown  in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=way%20up%20to%20becoming%2C%20way%20up%20to%20become&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cway%20up%20to%20becoming%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cway%20up%20to%20become%3B%2Cc0).

The reason is that in "way up to + ing"  the "to" is a preposition, it is not part of an infinitive verb.

Comment: She worked her way up: to becoming the best player

Comment: Four points and no explanation of the difference in meaning? Hm....

Answer (score 2):

In "Work your way up to become a director", 'to' goes with 'become' to mean "in order to become". It would be saying that the purpose of working your way up was to become a director.

In "work your way up to becoming a director", 'to' makes the the indirect object of "work your way up": there's no expressed purpose.

Because of the meaning of the phrase "work your way up", there's little difference. But the structures are rather different.

Comment: **to become** need not mean "in order to" (i.e. intention) but can express an outcome or result. For example: *He rose in the public's eye to become president.*   or *Most members of the climbing party perished on the mountain, but he survived to become famous*.

Comment: @Colin Fine I agree there is little difference in meaning. That said, there can a slight difference in meaning. Work your way up to becoming a director implies: working your way up to the state or condition where or when you can become a director. That said, I'm upvoting this even if you downvoted me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, /work one's way up/ is an idiom.

His song worked its way up the chart **to become** number one.

The same meaning semantically as: His song worked its way up the chart **and became** number one. It is the **outcome**.

versus

His song worked its way up the chart to becoming number one.

The same meaning semantically as: While his song was becoming number one, it worked its way up the chart.

Though the ing form is not as common.

Though in some cases, it might be more common in another type of sentence: 
**She ate her way through all the muffins to becoming thoroughly ill**.

to becoming = to reaching the state of being thoroughly ill.

For me, the ing is the state or condition of a person or thing.